# How to reset textboxes to zero value when 2 textboxes are used by using an onchange event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, onchange

If I am using two text boxes to convert a measurement to another. It shouldn't reset the values to zero. However, I am using more than two text boxes it should reset all textboxes to zero values.

I can simply do this using onsubmit and onclick events, but how to do it when using an onchange event? Since each textbox has its own method or function. I am lost. Is there a way to know if I am using more than 2 of the textfields and reset it to zero?

```js
function convertfttocm(feet) {
  var cm = feet * 12 * 2.54;
  document.getElementById("ansfeet").value = cm.toFixed(2);
}

function feet(feet) {
  var feet = 0;
  document.getElementById("feet").value = cm.toFixed(2);
}

function convertkmtomi(kilometres) {
  var mi = kilometres * (1 / 1.609344);
  document.getElementById("anskm").value = mi.toFixed(2);
}

function kilometres(kilometres) {
  var kilometres = 0;
  document.getElementById("km").value = mi.toFixed(2);
}

function convertcmtoin(centimetre) {
  var inch = centimetre * (1 / 2.54);
  document.getElementById("anscm").value = inch.toFixed(2);
}

function centimetres(centimetres) {
  var centimeres = 0;
  document.getElementById("cm").value = inch.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Feet to Centimetre<br>
<input type="number" name="feet" id="feet" onchange="convertfttocm(this.value);"><br>
<input type="number" name="ansfeet" id="ansfeet" onchange="feet(this.value)"><br><br> 

Kilometres to Miles<br>
<input type="number" name="km" id="km" onchange="convertkmtomi(this.value);"><br>
<input type="number" name="anskm" id="anskm" onchange="kilometres(this.value);"><br><br>

Centimetres to Inches<br>
<input type="number" name="cm" id="cm" onchange="convertcmtoin(this.value);"><br>
<input type="number" name="anscm" id="anscm" onchange="centimetres(this.value);">
```

Comment: some of your functions (the ones not starting with the word "convert") are trying to access variables that are within the scope of other functions. i doubt this is your intent, it just looks like a copy/paste error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but since you are hard coding all your calculations and conditions, you can do the following. Example:

```
function convertkmtomi(kilometres) {
  var mi = kilometres * (1 / 1.609344);
  document.getElementById("anskm").value = mi.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("_YOURID_").value = '';
}
```

You can apply all the permutations and see if this works for you.